# What happened with Eve and the stick?

Tags: grimm

When Eve touches the staff portion that Nick and Monroe found in the Black Forest, she is healed of the injuries that she sustained at the hands of Bonaparte. Then *something* seems to happen, and she woges. Afterward, she says she feels "different."

1. The most obvious hypothesis would be that it "healed" Eve of her Hexenbiest powers. But the evidence is all over the place for this. On the one hand, she seemed to have trouble woging after touching the stick, and notably refrained from using her powers much during the following episodes. On the other hand, she woged when the Zerstorer grabbed her, and even did it voluntarily in order to open a grimoire.
2. The logical next assumption would be that it healed her of whatever turned her into "Eve," restoring her more to Juliette's personality. But she later says quite strongly that she *is* Eve, and not Juliette.

Neither one of these theories seems quite right. Did the stick do one of these things? Both? Neither?

Comment: this one I'm less sure of, but it definitely has something to do with making her "more pure" -- I suspect it may have "healed" her of her sins, in some way that was incompatible with being a creature that seems inherently "bad"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After her interaction with the "stick" Eve became more like the old Juliette, but it was more of removing all the emotional repression she was experiencing.

Here is an interview between TVLINE and series co-creators David Greenwalt and James Kouf.

> TVLINE | Eve showing signs of Juliette returning: What can you tell me about what’s really going on?
>
> GREENWALT | Well, the feelings have come back.
>
> KOUF | The stick opened up part of her. There are unintended consequences to the use of that stick. So, just like everything else.
>
> GREENWALT | There’s part of her that was dead, that she had killed, that they had killed. Suddenly it was awakened. And because she’s a Hexenbiest, it had a super effect. So we’ll have to see what happens with the Eve side of her personality and now having all these feelings, which is going to include a lot of guilt. It’ll be complex. - [Grimm Finale Recap Season 5 TVLINE interview](http://tvline.com/2016/05/20/grimm-finale-recap-season-5-rosalee-pregnant-meisner-dead-died-juliette/)

Comment: Ah, finally. Who are these people giving the interview, again?

Comment: @Adamant I added their positions on the show